Click a div class on Selenium VBA, no button
I'm trying to click on a specific place in a web site using Selenium from VBA
This is part of the snipped HTML that I want to click:
<li><a href="" id="sourceResults-nextPage" class="btn btn-link" title="Next page" 
onclick="ResultsTables['sourceResults'].setRange (20, 20); ResultsTables['sourceResults'].onCriteriaChanged (); return false;">
<span class="ico-navigate-right blueText" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>

As you can see there's no "<button>" there, so I cannot call (?) it for the click.
The next <li> looks the same, but it only changes the title:
title="Next 5 pages"

What I did, I try to use FindElementByCCS:
bot.FindElementByCss("class.btn.btn-link span.ico-navigate-right.blueText").Click

It says "NoSuchElementError"
Also I've tried:
bot.FindElementByXPath("//'li'[@class='btn btn-link']//span[@class='ico-navigate-right blueText'").Click

This returns me: InvalidSelectorError
What can I do to fix this?
Thanks!

The css and the xpath selector used is incorrect. I would suggest a revisit of these concepts. According to the HTML snippet shared, the css select and xpath selectors should be as follows:
CSS Selector:
Old:
bot.FindElementByCss("class.btn.btn-link span.ico-navigate-right.blueText").Click

Corrected:
bot.FindElementByCss("#sourceResults-nextPage .blueText").Click

There is no class tag in HTML, it's an attribute. Also, you should have a locator strategy while locating elements. In an ideal case, the order of precedence should be ids, classes, tags and text.
